# What do you call someone who needs to be approved, approvee?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know:
One who reviews = reviewer
One who undergoes a review = reviewee

I thought:
One who approves = approver
A person seeking someone's approval = approvee

But I found that there is no word like approvee. What is the appropriate word for this meaning?

More specifically, suppose X needs something to be approved and Y is the person who can approve X's things.
Now, Y is approver of X.
X is *what* of Y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another word might be [*candidate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/candidate):

> 1. A person who is running in an election or who is applying to a position for a job.

Answer (score 6):

The question here is whether this person you're looking to name is the one *undergoing* approval, or one who *puts forth something for approval*. If I need my boss's signature to approve a vacation, he's the approver, but the *vacation request* is the approvee, not me. I'm just the one who made the request.

Loans are approved. Requests are approved. People, in general, aren't. There is a related phrase, "seeking someone's approval", which means seeking someone's good will, but there the approver in question isn't *approving you*, he's *approving **of** you*.

So to find the right word here, you'd need to give more specific context. In many cases, @user3306356's suggestion of *applicant* will be appropriate. Look for the action which leads to the approval process.

Comment: What you understand is correct. I mean 'the person who is seeking someones approval'.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps ***applicant***

> ODE: *a person who makes a formal application for something, especially a job*.

Usually someone who needs something approved has to apply for something first.

Edit

> OP: *What you understand is correct. I mean 'the person who is seeking someones approval*'. –  Mohayemin

Then you're looking for: **approval seeker**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *[candidate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candidate)* or *[examinee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/examinee).*

Answer (score 1):

I agree the question is very general and has many answers depending on specifics. This applies to your parallel example of **reviewer** too: I have been a reviewer, but NEVER considered my vict... er, subjects **reviewees**. They were **performers, artists, writers, authors**, etc. As to approval, the person quailing before the gatekeeper may be **applicant, supplicant, employee, candidate, probationer, trainee, rookie, protege, lover, butt-kisser...**